# Qt Visual Studio Community Add-in

Tags: visual-studio, qt, qt-creator, visual-studio-2015

Does QT Visual Studio Addin support Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition?

I try to instal in my VS but this say:

https://wiki.qt.io/Visual_Studio_Add-in

> These instructions refer to Visual Studio 2012. Replace any references
>   to VS2012 with the appropriate file for your VS version (2008, 2010
>   and 2012 supported).

Answer (score 2):

[Qt 5.6](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt-5.6-release) has not shipped and is the first to support VS 2015. At least it will be officially built with it. I don't know if the add-on will be available at that time.

EDIT September, 2016:  There is now [Visual Studio Add-In to Qt VS Tools (Beta)](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/08/11/from-visual-studio-add-in-to-qt-vs-tools-beta/).

In the meantime, there is [this add-on](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c89ff880-8509-47a4-a262-e4fa07168408) which emulates the official add-on in VS 2015.

Comment: This addin have to many bugs. First cant setup it bcs he dont like MinGW `Qt in the given path was built using MinGW` that error am geting when try to set path.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Qt5Package in Visual Studio 2015 with the Qt 5.6.0 Beta release. I found when I tried to add Qt 5.6.0 Beta in the extension I got the error "This Qt version uses an unsupported makefile generator (used: MSVC.NETMSBUILD, supported: MSVC.NET, MSBUILD)". The workaround is in C:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2015\mkspecs\common\msvc-desktop.conf Qt 5.6.0 splits all the version-specific changes into a separate file msvc-base.conf. If you copy the contents of this file and replace the line "include(msvc- base.conf)" in mscv-desktop.conf then Qt5Package recognises the Qt 5.6.0 Beta with no problems.

Note this still needs to be fixed in Qt5Package.